# Neo4j apoc.number.format function inconsistency between the desktop and docker

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

lately i experienced a strange behavior on apoc.number.format function, the desktop version(running on MacOS) and the docker one does not return the same value, down below the code snippet:

```
RETURN apoc.number.format(45.67123, '#,##0.00000', 'it') as value;
```

Desktop result: 45.67123

Docker result: 45,67123

I will be very thankful to understand why ?

Comment: It's returning the same 45,67123 on desktop also.

Comment: Maybe you copied the incorrect text.

Comment: To specify i am using in docker-compose this image version: image: neo4j:4.4.5 and the desktop version is also 4.4.5